# AWS Athena/Glue: Add partition to the data catalog using AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue, amazon-athena, aws-glue-data-catalog

I want to add manually a partiton to the datacalaog.
I can do it using Athena editor but i want to make it using a shell script that i can parameter and schedule.

Here's an example of my sql command to add a partition:

```
ALTER TABLE tab ADD PARTITION (year='2020', month='10', day='28', hour='23') LOCATION 's3://bucket/data/2020/10/28/23/'
```

i want to do the same thing with a shell command.
I think that i can use Glue APi: create-partition

Doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/glue/create-partition.html

I'm trying but there something wrong with the format of the parameter that i add.

Comment: one simple way of doing this is to first do a get-partition api call then pass requited parameters from this output  as input to create-partition api call

Comment: i have a problem with the synstax

Comment: Can you update your question with what you tried with script and error messages?